# Weird behavior while trying to control Paper.js from javascript directly

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm working on a project that requires me to control paper via javascript rather than using the normal paperscript route. I'm currently stuck because of a weird behavior that I can't seem to figure out. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm running

```
paper.install(window);
$(document).ready(function() { 
    paper.setup("canvas");
    Game.ship = new Ship(view.center, 1) // Essentially calls new Raster("imgid"); and positions it
    view.draw(); 
});
```

For some reason, this code is resulting in a blank canvas. What's weird is that if I call `new Ship(...)` in my dev console after a few seconds, the raster renders just fine on the canvas, as it should. I've also noticed that when I look at the value of `Game.ship.elem.__canvas`, I see a canvas element with a size of 32, 32, even though no such canvas exists in the DOM.

I'm assuming this has something to do with timing, but I can't seem to figure out what I have to do to make it work, other than the incredibly messy approach of using a setTimeout to create the raster a few seconds after `$(document).ready()` is called.

Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on here, or something that could lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I managed to figure it out on my own. For anyone who's running into this, the problem was actually because the `ready()` function was being called *before* the image had finished loading.

Because of this, the `new Raster()` call was loading a nonexistant image into the canvas, causing a blank result!

Comment: I ran into the same thing when working with paper rasters. I ended up using [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).